# VHDL - Conditional compilation

Tags: compilation, vhdl, standards

My VHDL testbench uses some features that are specific to VHDL'2008 but, depending on what exactly I'm testing or which software I'm using for the simulation, it cannot always be compiled in VHDL'2008.

To cope with that, I created 2 versions of this testbench :

- The full version, compiled in VHDL'2008.
- The light one, with all VHDL'2008 lines deleted, compiled in VHDL'93.

However, maintaining two nearly identical versions of this testbench is really an annoying thing to do, so I would like to merge them in some way.

I first thought I could use a generic and an "IF .. GENERATE" statement but this obviously doesn't allow me to '93-compile a file with '2008 features.

Is there a way to merge these 2 files and still compile the result with VHDL'93 ?

Comment: Have you tried a pre-processor? You could use the common #ifdef #else #endif approach. Or do you desire a pure VHDL solution?

Comment: The m4 preprocessor is suited to these sorts of problems and is more generalized than the C preprocessor. Another option you may be able to try is to isolate the 2008 specific code into its own package and implement a '93 equivalent that can be swapped in for tooling that requires it. Library mappings can then be used to select which one is active in simulation. That would avoid the hassles of generating intermediate files and integrating that into the simulation process.

Comment: I am more interested in a pure VHDL solution honestly. However, if I can't do what I want this way, I may try a pre-processor, thanks.

Comment: Kevin Thibedeau : what I use is hierarchical accesses (ex : TEST_SIGNAL  <= << signal uut_0.signal_to_test : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) >>;) and I could not isolate them into their package. I expected to find something with all the others 2008 functions but I may not be searching at the right place or for the right thing..

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 -- Pragmas**

If the code that uses VHDL 2008 doesn't replaces other pieces of the code (i.e., the code using VHDL 2008 does extra stuff), you can use pragmas such as

```
vhdl_93_component_u : foo_93 port map ( clk => clk, out => out);
-- rtl_synthesis off
vhdl_2008_component_u : foo_2008 port map ( clk => clk, out => out);
-- rtl_synthesis on
```

Also, check *if* your tool accepts enabling and disabling interpretation of pragmas and *which* pragmas it accepts. `-- rtl_synthesis on/off` is an example here.

**Option 2 -- Different files**

If you can split your code in 3 (testbench top, VHDL '93 code, VHDL 2008 code), you can compile only the file you need (assuming same package/architecture/entity names).

---

If you can't refactor your code to use something like this, I suggest you review the way you are implementing your testbench.

Comment: (Late comment, sorry).
Pragmas are ok but I wanted something easily compatible with different tools. Options 2 seems more like it, the 93 and 2008 code would have 90% in common but the good thing to do would be to isolate these 10 % into distinct files (in functions/procedures perhaps).

On a more general note I think that the way I designed my testbench was indeed not convenient..